# Como copiar una filas especifica dinamicamente con js o jquery a otra tabla a traves de un boton?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tablas

espero que tengan un buen dia, tengo el siguiente codigo que genera una tabla de manera dinamica a partir del resultado de una query en base de datos, basicamente es una lista de productos:

```
      $(".outer_div").append(
        '<div class="table-responsive"><table id= "r_table" class = "table table-checkable dataTable no-footer "></table></div class="table-responsive">'
      );
      let table = $("#r_table");

      let secRow = $(document.createElement("tr"));

      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
          secRow.append(cellHead.text("Código"));
          table.append(secRow);
        } else if (i == 1) {
          let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
          secRow.append(cellHead.text("Proveedor"));
          table.append(secRow);
        } else if (i == 2) {
          let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
          secRow.append(cellHead.text("Producto"));
          table.append(secRow);
        } else if (i == 3) {
          let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
          secRow.append(cellHead.text("Precio"));
          table.append(secRow);
        } else if (i == 4) {
          let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
          secRow.append(cellHead.text("Acciones"));
          table.append(secRow);
        }
      }

      $.each(datos, (index, value) => {

        let row = $(document.createElement("tr")).attr(
          "id",
          value["id"] + "row"
        );
        let secRow = $(document.createElement("tr"));



        for (let prop in value) {

          let cell = $(document.createElement("td")).attr(
            "id",
            value["id"] + "menu"
          );
          $("th").css("background-color", "#1bc5bd");


          cell.text(value[prop]);
          row.append(cell);
        }
        row.append(
          //Boton de agregar
          '<td><center><button onclick="cloneRow(\"'+'1row'+'\")"  class="envio btn btn-link-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button></center></td>'
        );




        table.append(row);

      });
```

Pero quiero lograr hacer que, en lo que de el boton que se genera en cada fila en la columna de acciones, al darle click me copie los datos de la fila entera y me lo guarde en otra tabla que debe ser generada en otro form para posteriormente mandarla a traves de un ajax a otra parte.

aqui le dejo la imagen de la tabla que se me genera dinamicamente con los botones

[image: tabla que se me genera dinamicamente]

Y este seria la tabla a donde mostraria la row en cuestion al darle click al boton de la fila especifica

```
<table id="resultados"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo simplificado para que veas como lo hago.

1.- selecciono el elemento con jquery

2.- copio el elemento

3.- pego el elemento

```js
var table = document.getElementById("t02");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
//var row = table.insertRow($('#t01 tbody tr td')[1]);
function ditto(identifier){
$('#t02').append($('#t01 tbody tr')[identifier].cloneNode(true))
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

table{width:100%;}table, th, td{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}th, td{padding: 15px; text-align: left;}table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #eee;}table tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #fff;}table th{background-color: black; color: white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<table id="t01"> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th> 
</tr><tr> <td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50<button onclick="ditto(1)">+</button></td>
</tr><tr> <td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94<button onclick="ditto(2)">+</button></td>
</tr><tr> <td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80<button onclick="ditto(3)">+</button></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
<table id="t02"> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th> </tr></table>
</div>
```